# Is it possible to create a proxy failover with Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub, zyte

Is it possible to create a proxy failover within Scrapy, so that when one fails the other will take over scraping the rest of the requests? I would of thought that it would be done using the retry middleware, but I don't really have a clue how to create one.

I have found a few examples online but none using two API SDK proxies. From the research i have done i think it can be done using retry middleware, but i dont think i quite understand how to do it.

FYI - The proxies im using are Zyte proxy manager and Scrapeops.io

Comment: Can You clarify the meaning of _using two API SDK proxies_ ? - are You aimed to use.. multiple proxy providers on single job? and.. disable "bad" ones during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

That is what middlewares are.

YOUR REQUEST -> RETRY_MIDDLEWARE -> CUSTOM_HEADER_MIDDLEWARE -> SERVER

So, when you make a request, it should pass through all middlewares before being sent to the server.

They can, however, do whatever they want; for example, RETRY MIDDLEWARE can explicitly return and not pass the request to the next middleware.

So you'll need to write your **own** middleware that will change the proxy if it fails.